# How to make a discord bot add you as friend

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot, and I want to add it to group DM's so I can keep my server levels lower. However, you can't add people who aren't friends to group DM's. Is there a way to get a discord bot to accept friend requests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not possible. Bot accounts do not have permission to use Discord's relationships endpoint. This means no friending and no blocking, and by extension means no bots in group DMs.