# DMing friends discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

What I want to do is when the bot starts up, grab the friends list and DM everyone on it. I can't use ctx as on_ready doesn't support it. My code so far:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready(msg):
    for x in bot.user.friends:
        e = x.id
        await x.send('hi')
```

Comment: You mean send a private message to everyone on the server? You are automatically friends with the bot when you share a server with it.

Comment: No. I mean using a self bot.

Comment: The support for self-bots is over, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

[Discord bots can't have friends](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50337904/15446995), but you can have a list of people that you can DM a message to. This is an example:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for friend in [listofuserids]:
        await friend.send("hi")
```

`listofuserids` should be a list of your friends' Discord IDs. For more information on how to get a user's Discord ID, read [this](https://techswift.org/2020/04/22/how-to-find-your-user-id-on-discord/).

Comment: I am using a self bot.

Comment: Aren't those against discord's TOS?

Comment: idk. It's just a proof of concept though.

Comment: @Ethansocal Yes, they are